# How to Redirect From VF page to Standard Recordtype Picklist page

Tags: visualforce

I have a `Visualforce Page`, on which I need to create Hyperlink and when user click the link it should redirect to Standard Recordtype  page of a custom Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
 String objKeyPrefix = CustomObject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
 Redirect to url in this format:
 https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=objectId&retURL=%2FobjKeyPrefix%2Fo&save_new_url=%2FobjKeyPrefix%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252FobjKeyPrefix%252Fo
 where objectId is the id of the custom object you get from setup.
```

Comment: if we use the ent=objectId, will it work in all environments. because ID will be different for DEV,TEST and Prod right?